# How do i get the before_save value in the controller in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, save

```
def update
    @product_category = @business_category.product_categories.find(params[:id])
    product_category_was = @business_category.product_categories.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product_category.update_attributes(params[:product_category])
        share_associations(@product_category, product_category_was) if in_params('_maps_attributes', 'product_category')

        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to(admin_product_categories_path, :notice => 'Product category was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.js
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product_category.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The function share_associations has the parameters @product_category and product_category_was. The problem is, when i call product_category_was.send('images') for example (which i have to call using send since the call is dynamic) it obviously pulls the newest associated images and not the images that were associated. Is there anyway i can get the object to get the images that were associated at the point in time it was made?

Comment: Probably need to see the model code to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a *deep copy* of your object, because normal association (`=`) will only create a reference:

```
product_category_was = Marshal::load(Marshal::dump(@product_category))
```

This might not work for all kinds of objects, but for normal Rails objects this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what arnep is talking about, nor what problem you're getting.  What you're doing works for me on two different finds through an association, and so it should.

```
irb(main):016:0> s = School.first
=> #<School id: 2, name: "Bar", created_at: "2011-04-09 17:48:57", updated_at: "2011-05-13 09:13:38", confirmed: nil, zipcode: nil>
irb(main):017:0> g1 = s.grades.find 4
=> #<Grade id: 4, name: "4th", type: nil, school_id: 2, created_at: "2011-04-19 03:17:49", updated_at: "2011-05-13 09:15:17">
irb(main):018:0> g2 = s.grades.find 4
=> #<Grade id: 4, name: "4th", type: nil, school_id: 2, created_at: "2011-04-19 03:17:49", updated_at: "2011-05-13 09:15:17">
irb(main):019:0> g1.update_attributes :name => '5th'
=> true
irb(main):020:0> g2
=> #<Grade id: 4, name: "4th", type: nil, school_id: 2, created_at: "2011-04-19 03:17:49", updated_at: "2011-05-13 09:15:17">
irb(main):021:0> g1
=> #<Grade id: 4, name: "5th", type: nil, school_id: 2, created_at: "2011-04-19 03:17:49", updated_at: "2011-05-13 09:16:02">
irb(main):022:0>
```

In fact, usually people are asking the inverse question - how to get an already instantiated object to reload from the DB.  The problem is probably in your `share_associations` method, or something else you're not showing yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do something that works for now. It's not the greatest way, but it works for now. I basically created an empty array and pushed the product_categories array into it. This made it so the value was no longer a call so the value does not change. Hopefully this will help someone else eventually.

```
def update
    @product_category = @business_category.product_categories.find(params[:id])
    if in_params('_maps_attributes', 'product_category')
      media_was = Array.new
      media_was = media_was | @business_category.product_categories.find(params[:id]).send(map_type('product_category').pluralize)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product_category.update_attributes(params[:product_category])
        share_associations(@product_category, media_was) if in_params('_maps_attributes', 'product_category')

        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to(admin_product_categories_path, :notice => 'Product category was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.js
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product_category.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```